# How to include a session variable in the update command of a datagrid asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, sql-update, sqldatasource

Super Beginner Here:)

My original scope was a simple datagrid where I could use the prebuilt `vs2019 asp.net` delete and edit properties of the **datagrid**.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditItemSoftDelete.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProcessingSchedule8.WebForm5" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<p>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ActivityID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Division" HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="Division" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Start" HeaderText="Start" SortExpression="Start" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="End" HeaderText="End" SortExpression="End" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="Note" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grouping" HeaderText="Grouping" SortExpression="Grouping" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Updated" HeaderText="Updated" SortExpression="Updated" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Format" HeaderText="Format" SortExpression="Format" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityID" HeaderText="ActivityID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ActivityID" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="EditFlag" HeaderText="EditFlag" SortExpression="EditFlag" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="DeleteFlag" HeaderText="DeleteFlag" SortExpression="DeleteFlag" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EditDate" HeaderText="EditDate" SortExpression="EditDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DeleteDate" HeaderText="DeleteDate" SortExpression="DeleteDate" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProcessingScheduleDevlConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="UPDATE [Activities] SET [Updated] = 1, [EditFlag] = 1, [DeleteFlag] = 1, **[UserID] = This is where I want to get and put the anumber into the table**  WHERE [ActivityID] = @ActivityID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Activities] ([Year], [Division], [Department], [Type], [Start], [End], [Description], [Note], [Grouping], [Updated], [Format], [EditFlag], [DeleteFlag], [UserID], [EditDate], [DeleteDate]) VALUES (@Year, @Division, @Department, @Type, @Start, @End, @Description, @Note, @Grouping, @Updated, @Format, @EditFlag, @DeleteFlag, @UserID, @EditDate, @DeleteDate)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Activities]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Activities] SET [Year] = @Year, [Division] = @Division, [Department] = @Department, [Type] = @Type, [Start] = @Start, [End] = @End, [Description] = @Description, [Note] = @Note, [Grouping] = @Grouping, [Updated] = @Updated, [Format] = @Format, [EditFlag] = @EditFlag, [DeleteFlag] = @DeleteFlag, [UserID] = @UserID, [EditDate] = @EditDate, [DeleteDate] = @DeleteDate WHERE [ActivityID] = @ActivityID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ActivityID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Division" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Start" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="End" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Note" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Grouping" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Updated" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Format" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EditFlag" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DeleteFlag" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EditDate" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DeleteDate" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Division" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Start" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="End" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Note" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Grouping" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Updated" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Format" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EditFlag" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DeleteFlag" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EditDate" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DeleteDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ActivityID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Now my boss wants me to do a soft delete instead and also insert the **user's ID** that they entered on the login page. I am sure it is ugly but so far I simply changed the delete command to an update statement and I am now correctly setting the update and delete flags and they are working in the table, exciting!

Now I can't understand how to get the **useriD** (simple text box, we call it a number) which the user entered in the login page (a different web form) and use that value in the update.

Thanks so much.

Comment: We have no knowledge of how you authenticate users.  Is it LDAP based?  Or what?  How do you verify the user is authenticated when you display your page with the datagrid on it?

Comment: Hi! No authenticate just a simple textbox that the user types in their number.

Comment: I did figure out how to get the number to populate in a textbox on this form. So I know that the <asp:TextBox id="anum" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox> is grabbing the correct value. I just don't understand the syntax to get it into the update statement. Thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the update statement you're referring to.